# How to do order by desc when the time is same in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a log table which has column time(DATETIME). I wanted to sort this table by time. 
It is working perfectly when there are distinct time values.
But when there are same time in the column, that rows wont sort.

This table values are inserted by automated process

```
|user_id| type       | title      |      time           |
--------------------------------------------------------
|150    | add_note   | Note added | 2018-06-13 08:30:10 |
|150    | send_email | Email sent | 2018-06-13 08:30:10 |
|150    | add_tag    | Tag added  | 2018-06-13 08:30:10 |
|150    | add_note   | Note added | 2018-06-13 08:30:10 |
```

This is the query I'm using to sort data

```
SELECT * FROM log ORDER BY time DESC
```

I want to get rows in reverse order if the time is same.
Please help.

Comment: you can order by more than one column,first order by time,if time is the same,order by the other column

Comment: in this case user other column after time in order by.

Comment: you need a second column two sort. show your table.

Comment: there are no other columns which I can use for sorting :(

Comment: How do you know they're not sorted?

Comment: because they are in same order even if I use 'ORDER BY ASC'

Comment: Can you us some table data which better explains the problem?  Your sample data is all the same.

Comment: @pradeep - *reverse order* - which column reverse? same time is sorted fine with `ASC` and `DESC`.

Comment: @pradeep, no, they're not, it just looks that way.

Comment: Did you remove the fractional seconds from the datetime column?

Comment: I see your data, and once more:  how do you know the rows are not in descending order?

Comment: "This table values are inserted by automated process".  Yes, that would have been a hell of a typist.

Comment: these are the nodes of a campaign. it will first add_note then send_email then add_tag etc..

Comment: You're wrong, since there are two "add_note".

Comment: one campaign can have same node many times. this is like campaigns in AgileCRM

Comment: If you don't rebuild your table as in my answer, your problem can't be solved.

Comment: Is that the only solution?

Comment: I am quite sure.  This is why you have to analyze the problem before you design the database.  You need to study all questions (queries) that may be asked.  Now you will need to retrace in what order the records were added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a sequence column to your table, add that column to the order by.

Comment: You can alter that table, update the new column with a row number.